# Auto generated build manifest file AndroidManifest.xml installs unwanted application on device

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm using Todd's ProgressWheel in my project and every time I install my app two icons appear on the device , one for my actual app and one for ProgressWheel. I believe the problem lays in the auto-generated manifest file from ProgressWheel ,which I cannot edit:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.todddavies.components.progressbar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.todddavies.components.progressbar.main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I know that "action MAIN" and "category LAUNCHER" are causing the issue, but how do I take care of this if I cannot edit the file as it gets overwritten every time I compile.
The ProgressWheel is included in my project through dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.github.Todd-Davies:ProgressWheel:[1.0]'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Auto generated build manifest file AndroidManifest.xml installs unwanted application on device

No, it does not.

> I'm using Todd's ProgressWheel in my project and every time I install my app two icons appear on the device , one for my actual app and one for ProgressWheel.

More accurately, two icons appear in your home screen's launcher. These represent two activities, but only one app.

> but how do I take care of this if I cannot edit the file as it gets overwritten every time I compile

The best answer is to use a better progress wheel library, as we have [a few dozen of them](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/76), and the one you chose is poorly packaged.

If you *really* want to use the library, in your own manifest, as a child of the `<application>` element, add:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.todddavies.components.progressbar.main"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

This will require you to add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` namespace declaration to your `<manifest>` element.

What this `<activity>` element does is say "hey, build system, we are pulling in a `com.todddavies.components.progressbar.main` activity from a library, but get rid of it". This will be handled as part of [the manifest merger process](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:node-markers).

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive and helpful answer. The 'tools:node="remove" ' worked.